# Unable to start ara

Tags: ara

I have installed ara as per documentation 
https://ara.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html

however when I try to access it from url it does not load. I am not sure where are the ara logs.

Kindly find below information from logs

```
[jim@centos74.master /data/OnlyOnMyPC/ansible]type ara
ara is /bin/ara
[jim@centos74.master /data/OnlyOnMyPC/ansible]file /bin/ara
/bin/ara: Python script, ASCII text executable
[jim@centos74.master /data/OnlyOnMyPC/ansible]/bin/ara
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/ara", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ara/shell.py", line 73, in main
    return aracli.run(argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cliff/app.py", line 279, in run
    result = self.interact()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cliff/app.py", line 318, in interact
    from .interactive import InteractiveApp
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cliff/interactive.py", line 20, in <module>
    import cmd2
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cmd2.py", line 226, in <module>
    import gtk
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    _init()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 52, in _init
    _gtk.init_check()
RuntimeError: could not open display
[jim@centos74.master /data/OnlyOnMyPC/ansible]systemctl status ara
Unit ara.service could not be found.
```

I would greatly appreciate your assistance.

End game is to have ara working so we can see statistical information of playbooks etc

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of ara and just came across this question.

The quick start guide in the README should hopefully allow you to get started: https://github.com/ansible-community/ara#quickstart

If you have any questions, please feel free to reach out to us on [Slack or IRC](https://ara.recordsansible.org/community/).

Thanks !